# ng-repeat track by $index and removing elements from the array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using `track by $index` because I want to allow repeated elements in my array, but at the same time this is causing a side effect when removing elements from this collection.

I have this set of players which is declared in the controller as `$scope.players = []`.

You can populate this array as follows:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="player">
<button ng-click="addPlayer()">
```

`addPlayer()` just pushes the `player` model to the `players` array:

```
$scope.addPlayer = function() {
    if (!$scope.player)
        return;
    $scope.players.push($scope.player);
    $scope.player = null;
};
```

And the collection is shown using `ng-repeat`. But also when an item is clicked on, it should be deleted.

```
<div ng-repeat="player in players track by $index" ng-click="deletePlayer($index)">
    {{player}}
</div>

$scope.deletePlayer = function(index) {
    if (index > -1)
        $scope.players.splice(index, 1);
};
```

The issue is that since it's tracking by index, when an element is removed the collection of players will be short by 1 because the collection has changed.

What I mean by this is the following: say I have the array of players `["p1", "p2", "p3"]`. If I remove one of these except the last, for example, `p1`, the `ng-repeat` is not showing `[p2, p3]` even though these are the contents of the array, but it shows just `p3`. This is what I mean when I say the collection is one element short.

I think the issue happens because it's unknown to `ng-repeat` in the `track by $index` mode that the length of the array has changed. Therefore, it's skipping one element when iterating through the changed array, because it's using the old indices to iterate it, I believe.

Is there a standard way of tackling this side effect?

Comment: Can you pease explain "removed the collection of players will be short by 1 because the collection has changed." after you spliced the item or before that ?

Comment: Yes let me edit my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can make each item in players array to be an object that has `name` and `id` properties. [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/0yxSB4Sjdgnep6Nhgq2P?p=preview).

```
Object.assign($scope, {
  players: [],
  player: '',
  addPlayer: function() {
    if(!$scope.player) {
      return 
    }

    $scope.players = $scope.players.concat({
      name: $scope.player,
      id: Date.now() //fake id (timestamp)
    })

    $scope.player = ''
  },

  deletePlayer: function(id) {
    $scope.players = $scope.players.filter(function(player){
      return player.id !== id
    })
  }
})

  <div ng-repeat="player in players track by player.id" ng-click="deletePlayer(player.id)">
    {{player.name}}
  </div>
```

Comment: I didn't know this way of assigning elements to the scope. Nice :)

Comment: @developer033 Actually this will work only in modern browsers. [angular.extend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend) is more production ready way.

Comment: Thanks for the info, @Yuri Tarabanko

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your deletePlayer function.  Your argument name is 'i' but you are trying to use 'index' instead.

This:

```
$scope.deletePlayer = function(i) {
  if (i > -1)
    $scope.players.splice(index, 1);
};
```

should be:

```
$scope.deletePlayer = function(i) {
  if (i > -1)
    $scope.players.splice(i, 1);
};
```

Comment: that obviously was a typo... it is not the real issue

Comment: @dabadaba - Ok, but by fixing the typo your function works.  At least it does in this plunker  https://plnkr.co/edit/qo3NF8SW79ZUH3y5b0ZN?p=info

Answer (score 0):

In the element you could use: `ng-click="remove(phones, $index)`

And in the code:

```
$scope.remove = function(array, index){
    array.splice(index, 1);
}
```

You shouldn't have any problems with this approach.